# BTEQ Teradata passing query variable to shell to script

Tags: shell, teradata

I am new to Teradata.I am having a problem with my BTEQ program. The BTEQ job passes a variable shell script. The purpose of the program to check for any null values in the summary table that is 2 months delay. Here is an example of the table (the purpose of the program: when The Summary table is missing two months, for example, Oct and Nov then flag=Y.  flag=Y  means YES that there are null values in the Summary table for the month of Oct and Nov. flag=N means there are no null values):

```
 dt_load           maxmth       summary
  12-SEP            Sep          Sep
  13 SEP            Sep
  29-SEP            Sep 
  2-Oct             Oct
  3-Oct             Oct      
  1-Nov             Nov
  2-Nov             Nov    

user="usr1"
pass="pass1"
SRC_DB="emp"
SOURCE_TABLE="summarytb"

FLAG =$(query_td)

td_query () { bteq << EOF |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//" 

${HOST}/${USER},${PASSWORD}
 DATABASE $SRC_DB;
 .set width 1000;
 .set titledashes off;

 SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM ${SRC_DB}.${SOURCE_TABLE};
 ( SELECT
     dt_load,
     summary ,
     maxmth,
  /*check for null 2 months back*/        
     MDIFF(summary, 2, maxmth, dt_load) AS diff1 
     FROM $SOURCE_TABLE
     Group by dt_load) AS a
     FROM 
   /*if summary field is null than insert 2*/ 
     ( SELECT *,
       COALESCE(a.diff1,2) AS diff (Select FROM a) AS  b
       FROM
  /* if diff= 2 than flag =Y else flag=N*/
     ( SELECT *,
       CASE
        When b.diff = 2  then  ‘Y ‘  ELSE  ‘N’
        End ) AS flag (SELECT c.diff FROM b) c
        FROM
   /*pass flag variable to shell script*/
         SELECT   '>'||' c.flag';
          $1
          .LOGOFF;
          .QUIT;
          .EXIT
           EOF
              }
          echo $FLAG

         if [ $FLAG='Y' ] then echo Run file1;
         exit 1
       fi
        IF [ $FLAG='N' ] then echo run file 2;
         exit 1
       fi
```

Comment: The only thing that jumps out to me is that your single quotes in statement below your comment "If diff=2..." Are not what Teradata is expecting. See the single quotes below "pass flag variable", those are what Teradata is expecting. Otherwise, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: In shell you have to define the function first and then you can use it (make sure the name is either td_query or query_td in both places)
The sql has a lot of problems.
No `.logon`, unnecessary (), at least one is not closed, `(Select FROM a) AS b` does not have a column selected, the first FROM has no select, ...
Why using two queries (indicated by two ';') and after that the content of $1, if you are interested only in one line of result?

First you have to build a query which creates a single row, single column as result.
And then you may place that in your function.